# Postfix - Bad recipient address syntax - email starting with dash/hyphen

Tags: debian, email, postfix

I am trying to send an email to a recipient with an email address starting with a hyphen/dash, e.g. -localpart@example.com

The recipient claims the mail address is correct.

mail.log shows:

```
postfix/smtpd[26055]: warning: Illegal address syntax from ...[...] in RCPT command: <-localpart@example.com>
```

I am using Postfix 2.11.3

Any idea how I can send emails to such an address?

Comment: The local part should be valid, although addresses don't commonly start with a hyphen. The obvious check is that there is an invalid character somewhere. Can you test by manually sending to the address on the command line or something like that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did

echo "Just a test" | mail -s Test -- -localpart@example.com

(the local part is just letters except for the hyphen and the domain as well - so nothing fancy there).

Response is

Final-Recipient: rfc822; -localpart@example.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.3
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; bad address syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Postfix to accept such addresses with option `allow_min_user = yes`.

The [postconf documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#allow_min_user) also explains why the default is to reject such addresses:

> Allow a sender or recipient address to have `-' as the first
>   character. By default, this is not allowed, to avoid accidents with
>   software that passes email addresses via the command line. Such
>   software would not be able to distinguish a malicious address from a
>   bona fide command-line option. Although this can be prevented by
>   inserting a "--" option terminator into the command line, this is
>   difficult to enforce consistently and globally.
>
> As of Postfix version 2.5, this feature is implemented by
>   trivial-rewrite(8). With earlier versions this feature was implemented
>   by qmgr(8) and was limited to recipient addresses only.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, postfix has a setting (allow_min_user) prohibiting you from sending mail to addresses starting with a hyphen due to security reasons:

> allow_min_user (default: no) Allow a sender or recipient address to
>   have `-' as the first character. By default, this is not allowed, to
>   avoid accidents with software that passes email addresses via the
>   command line...

More here:
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#allow_min_user